# opencv iplimage binarization

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an `IplImage` and I want to binarize (without using `cvThreshold` function) it using this following code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static IplImage* img ;

    img = cvLoadImage ("c:\\Mytest.jpg");

    for(int i=0;i<img->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<img->width;j++)
        {
            if (img->imageData[i*img->widthStep+j]<=10)
                ((uchar *)img->imageData)[i*img->widthStep+j]=255;
            else 
                ((uchar *)img->imageData)[i*img->widthStep+j]=0;
        }
    }

    cvShowImage("After",img);
    waitKey(0);
};
```

but this code affected only part of the image, like this:

[image]

Comment: please do *not* use the outdated c-api, they moved away from that 5 years ago already.

Comment: ok, to be fair - the reason it failed is, you're loading a rgb image, 3 bytes per pixel. your pointer calculation does not account for that

Answer (score 3):

see, it's a breeze with c++:

```
Mat img = imread("c:\\Mytest.jpg", 0); // load grayscale
Mat thresh = ( im <= 10 ); // that's it already!
imshow("After",img);
waitKey(0);
```

also look at [threshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold)